# Phonegap SQL database issue

Tags: sql, cordova

I am trying to learn how to work with phone gap. I have done a few sql tutorials and for some reason none of them are working for me. They just done seem to be creating the DB as expected. Is there a setting or permission I am missing somewhere?

Here is the result of the below code: http://madebyjohann.com/curatio/addweight.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
          <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width;" />
    <title>Open File</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="xui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" >

        var fileObject;

        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);

        function onDeviceReady() {
                window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccess, fail); 
        }

        function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getFile("readme.txt", {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);
    }

        function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
                fileObject = fileEntry;

                x$('#saveFile_btn').on('click', function() {
                        saveFileContent();
                });
    }

        function gotFileWriter(writer) {
        var myText = document.getElementById('my_text').value;
        writer.write(myText);

                writer.onwriteend = function(evt) {
                        x$('#message').html('<p>File contents have been written.<br /><strong>File path:</strong> ' + fileObject.fullPath + '</p>');

                        var reader = new FileReader();
                        reader.onload = function(evt) {
                                x$('#contents').html('<strong>File contents:</strong> <br />' + evt.target.result);
                        };
                        reader.readAsText(fileObject);
               };

    }

        function saveFileContent() {
                fileObject.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);
        }

        function fail(error) {
        alert(error.code);
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

        <input type="text" id="my_text" />
        <input type="button" id="saveFile_btn" value="Save" />

        <div id="message"></div>
        <div id="contents"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have by the way also tried the code directly copied and pasted from the phone gap website and that too did not work for me. I am testing it on a web browser, and Acer with Android 4.0 and an iPhone 5.

Comment: Please read my answer and if you have any questions make a command to my answer.  There severel general issues, so take your time.  I will try and answer as quickly as i can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)**

First of all your code is not working with SQL or any database.

What you are working with is the file system.  Two different things.

**2)**

You cant execuse phonegap code in your browser.  You need to create an app.

**3)**

The code thats on the website you posted isent the same as the one in your question.  I will only answer for what you posted here in thid question.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage

Read this link above to work with localstorage API.

Furthermore here is a tutorial you can read to, to learn phonegap and get a good start with it.

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/phonegap/phonegap-from-scratch/

This is just a copy paste:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Storage Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
        db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
    }

    // Populate the database
    //
    function populateDB(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)');
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (1, "First row")');
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (2, "Second row")');
    }

    // Transaction error callback
    //
    function errorCB(tx, err) {
        alert("Error processing SQL: "+err);
    }

    // Transaction success callback
    //
    function successCB() {
        alert("success!");
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Example</h1>
    <p>Database</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Daniel.I made a big mistake and copied the wrong code, sorry.

Comment: I ran the code through the Xcode emulator (as an app) and it still did not work. Do I need to set anything in the manifest file?

Comment: Well you need to add access to localstorage.  If you are using phonegap version 3+ there is a new documentation for that https://build.phonegap.com/docs/plugins-using.  If you are using phonegap version 2.9.0 or lower you can use the old config.xml plugin feature tags.

Comment: YEs, you need to add the access in your config.xml file.

Comment: Thanks a million Daniel.
I will give it a go later today. I knew I must be missing something small like that.